# RavenDB Management Studio - Delete Document

Tags: ravendb

Does anybody know how to delete a ravendb-document within RavenDB Management Studio?

If I go to the details-page of a document, I can do everything (including updates) but the delete-button is disabled.

I've already tried setting AnonymousAccess to "All" and restarted the server, but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to delete the document by right-mouse clicking on the document from one of the top level views, such as 'Documents', 'Summary', 'Collections', etc.

When I right mouse click from on of these views, I see these three options:
"Edit Document"
"Copy Document Id to Clipboard"
"Delete document"

I see the same thing as you in the 'Edit' detail screen; the "Delete" button is disabled.

You can also use the SET based operations as described here.
http://ravendb.net/documentation/set-based

Comment: Thank you! Right-clicking on the document within a top-level view did the trick! I just wonder, why the "delete" button in the details view is disabled... confusing.

Comment: It is a bug in an old version of the studio